# Large mysql dump failed to be imported

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, import

I have mysql dump called `dbBACKUP.sql` about 152 MB. It has thousands of records. I use the following command to import it:

```
mysql -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8 phpbb3 < dbBACKUP.sql
```

After supplying the password of the root, I go to phpmyadmin to check the data imported to the database. I notice slow increase in the amount of data imported by the changes in both total rows number and the total size in MB, till point it seems there is no any change with each refresh of phpmyadmin.

I believe this is may be a memory issue for the server. Is there any configuration settings allow to increase the memory used by MySQL. Or even any solution to increase the performance of this task?

This is occured on my own desktop based on Windows 7 64bit. The Mysql server is 5.6.16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a google search and found this blog that might help you: http://cmanios.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/import-a-large-sql-dump-file-to-a-mysql-database-from-command-line/

```
-- connect to database
mysql -u root -p

-- set network buffer length to a large byte number.
set global net_buffer_length=1048576;

-- set maximum allowed packet size to a large byte number.
set global max_allowed_packet=1073741824;

-- set read buffer size to a large byte number.
set global read_buffer_size=2147479552;

-- disable foreign key checking to avoid delays,errors and unwanted behaviour 
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

-- import your sql dump file
source C:\[your_path]\dbBACKUP.sql

-- enable foreign key checking after import
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: I noticed a warning in first two set command. However, I could not able to notice any notable increase in the performance. It may be due to those settings about buffer and packet did not applied. I will try to set them directly in my.ini

Comment: I looked up the max_values of the system variables and updated my post. Look here for descriptions of the sysvariables: [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use SOURCE command instead of redirecting your sql file.

```
mysql -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8
use phpbb3
source /full/path/to/your/dbBACKUP.sql
```

Comment: I believe it is a matter of my.ini configurations but I don't know what's and how is values to be.

Comment: Try to increase max_allowed_packet and read_buffer_size. max_allowed_packet = 200M
read_buffer_size = 2014K

Answer (score 1):

Also, you have to change it for both the client and the daemon mysqld server. Change the my.cnf or my.ini file under the [mysqld] section and set max_allowed_packet=1000M or you could run these commands in a MySQL console connected to that same server:

```
    set global net_buffer_length=1000000000; 
    set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
```

Use a very large value for the packet size, because they are in bytes and then restart your MySQL server.